# Fine uploader works in the same folder but not in another

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using this simple framework: https://github.com/panique/mini and this fineuploader S3 php file: https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo.php

This is my file structure

```
application
--controller
----mycontroller.php
--libs
----s3upload.php (not working)
--model

public
--css
--img
--js
----application.js
----fineuploader.min.js
----s3upload.php (working)
```

My fineuploader javascript funktion is in `application.js` and as you can see, both `application.js` and `fineuploader.min.js` is in the public folder js

Everything works fine if I put `s3upload.php` in my JS-folder. But I want to put s3upload.php in the `lib`  folder or somewhere else outside the pubic directory.

I have tested this that does not work

Put `s3upload.php` in the libs folder.

Create a new function in a controller

```
public function s3upload()
{
    require APP . '/libs/s3upload.php';
}
```

And update fineuploader javascript to

```
    signature: {
        endpoint: url + "myController/s3upload"
    },
```

I get this in chrome network -> signature -> response (no errors on the screen/website). And the file is not uploaded. I have tried turning off
notice (and all errors) in php which does not help.

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: headers in
>   **...application/libs/s3upload.php** on line **110**
>   {"invalid":true}

Line 110 in `s3upload.php`

```
 $headersStr = $contentAsObject["headers"];
```

The framework includes all the php files in the index file https://github.com/panique/mini/blob/master/public/index.php. I can do it but then I do not know which path I should write in fineuploader `signature: {` endpoint: